# make a python program have my UID to modificate a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, permissions

So, in short, I created a script (named main.py) in which there was a moment where I wrote in a file. It worked well. However, the permissions on this file had to be rwxrwxrw- and hence anyone could modify the file on the server. That's not what I wanted. So I changed the permissions to rwxrwxr-- and then I changed the code of main.py :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
text = "I want this text to appear in my file"
command = subprocess.Popen(["python", "modificateFile.py", str('"')+text+str('"')], stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) #I run another file that will do the task
for i in command.stderr:
    print(i.decode("utf-8")) #check if there is any error
```

code of modificateFile.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import platform
import os
import sys

UID = 1080 #my UID.. I don't really know if it's the right way to program this

if __name__ == "__main__":
    system = platform.system()
    if system == "Linux": #ok it may be useless
        os.setuid(UID) #            /!\ I THINK THAT'S WHERE THE PROBLEM IS /!\
        if len(sys.argv) > 1:
            with open("file.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                f.write(sys.argv[1])
        else:
            sys.stderr.write("not enough parameters to work") #didn't know which error I could raise.. 
#so as I already imported sys, I used this function
            exit(-1)
    else:
        sys.stderr.write("wrong OS : program only work on linux")
        exit(-1)
```

When I created this, I didn't know really what I was doing to be honest… I am learning programming.
Error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "modificateFile.py", line 11,
>   in os.setuid(UID) PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

I heard of SUID.. but I don't have root permissions.

Could someone explain what is wrong and what I could do ?
(if you need more elements, tell me it)

Answer (score 0):

ok…. I thought SUID was only available for root programs… I had already tested it for this program but it didn't work. However, I learnt after that SUID is not available for programs with a shebang at the beginning… So, I created a code in C to do that.